# How to add meta tag on head in cscart?

Tags: cs-cart

In `..skins/basic/customer/common_templates/image.tpl` I add code:

```
{hook name="index:meta"}
<meta property="og:image" content="{$config.current_location}{$config.full_host_name}{$icon_image_path|default:$config.no_image_path}" />
{/hook}
```

=> result can't add meta tag on head, It's add on body tag => How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the index.tpl file in your skin to make sure that meta.tpl is being included inside the head and not the body. That's where the hook gets inserted, so as long as it's inside the head then there's no reason it should appear outside.